# What if Chrome dev tools mobile not real?

Tags: javascript, css

I am a front-end engineer, but recently I find a circumstance happen usually.

That is what we set by media query for RWD and everything seem good in Chrome dev tools to switch to iphone5, iphone6, but when I really use my iPhone, open such as Safari, or Google App (maybe Chrome mobile), the style just go away.

Now people use mobile device a lot, so how do you overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out USB Debugging for the chrome browser or safari with android and iphone.

[Chrome USB Debugging]

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/